# How to mount Amazon EFS as data volume in ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

Userdata on launch configuration:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=prodcluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config

sudo yum install -y nfs-utils 
sudo mkdir /home/ec2-user/web_file_uploads 
sudo chmod 777 /home/ec2-user/web_file_uploads 

sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 fs-abcdef.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:/ /home/ec2-user/web_file_uploads
```

Task definition:

```
{
  "networkMode": "bridge",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "portMappings": [
        ...
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/src/temp_uploads/",
          "sourceVolume": "web_file_uploads",
          "readOnly": null
        }
      ],
      "name": "webapp",
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "image": "911911911.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/webapp:release6",
      "memoryReservation": 150
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [
    {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/home/ec2-user/web_file_uploads"
      },
      "name": "web_file_uploads"
    }
  ],
  "family": "webapp-task"
}
```

**Note**:
I have added required ports to security group. 
src/temp_uploads folder is required to have within all other container instances launched with this task definition.

**Problem**: 
If I mount it manually using `sudo mount ... folder1`, put some files there and mount the same to `sudo mount ... folder2` folder 2 contains the changes which shows it mounts correctly.

The problem is the volume mapped through the task definition doesn't map `efs`. Instead it puts/use content actually inside `/home/ec2-user/web_file_uploads`. 
How to make this volume actually mapped to `efs`

Comment: Any best practices I missed are welcome to mention

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem well. Do you want to have shared content in folder1 and folder2 when you put in folder1 files?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the lunch configuration to **restart docker service right after mounting EFS**. Then only ECS will use the mounted EFS as volume. Otherwise it will use the original directory (mount will be ignored).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=prodcluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
sudo yum install -y nfs-utils

sudo stop ecs
sudo mkdir /home/ec2-user/web_file_uploads
sudo chmod 777 /home/ec2-user/web_file_uploads
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 fs-abcdef.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:/ /home/ec2-user/web_file_uploads
sudo service docker restart
sudo start ecs
```

Note: ECS service will stop after restarting docker service as ECS Agent runs inside docker. You need to start ECS Service afterwards.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using `chmod 777`?